# Does virtual desktop in windows 10 have a separate registry

Tags: windows, windows-10

Does virtual desktop in windows 10 have a separate registry
I want to edit some things in my registry but i dont want to mess up with my pc. So it there any way other than Hyper V or these programs

Comment: The concept of virtual desktop is to allow users setup multiple independent workspaces to house different sets of windows(tasks or applications), which won’t have separate OS than the physical one.

Moreover, to perform tests on VM is a more convenient and safer method before applying changes into the actual machines. For windows10 itself, there is hype-v feature for users to utilize virtual machines or some other VM software program listed:4 best virtual machines for Windows 10
https://windowsreport.com/virtual-machine-software/

Answer (score 2):

For the Windows 10 Virtual Desktop (Task View button in Task Bar), the Registry is the same (only one) across all Desktops. If you edit the Registry in any Desktop, the edits affects the one Registry.

If you choose to use Virtual Machines (very different from Task View Desktops) by way of Hyper-V, VMware, or Virtual Box, then the Windows Guest machines that you build and use have their own Registries.

Virtual Machines as I described can be thought of as individual machines.

You can build test case applications in a copy of the machine and then revert back to the good machine after testing.